# How to use SAX parse xml with the same tag and multi-attribute

Tags: android, xml, sax

When I use SAX to parse this XML,I don't know how to get this three "link" tag's href attributes value by the three different "rel" attributes.

```
<entry>
<title>ahbei</title>
<link href="http://api.douban.com/people/1000001" rel="self" />
<link href="http://www.douban.com/people/ahbei/" rel="alternate" />
<link href="http://img3.douban.com/icon/u1000001-20.jpg" rel="icon" />
<uri>http://api.douban.com/people/1000001</uri>
</entry>
```

I can't get the "http://img3.douban.com/icon/u1000001-20.jpg" by this code.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equals("link") && (atts.getValue("rel") == "icon"))  // (*)
        {
            NowState = DBU_icon_url;
            DouBanUser.setIcon(atts.getValue(0));   
            return;
        }

    }
```

Thank you.

---

change
"`if (localName.equals("link") && (atts.getValue("rel") == "icon"))`"
=>
"`if (localName.equals("link") && atts.getValue("rel").equals("icon"))`"

Comment: What *are* you getting by this code?

Comment: try `if (localName.equals("link") && atts.getValue("rel").equals("icon"))`

Comment: I want to get the 3rd link's href value.

Comment: is it just me or does anyone think that SAX parsing is somewhat painful...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
NodeList link = elementW.getElementsByTagName("link");
int getLinkCount = link.getLength();
Element elementLink;
if (getLinkCount != 0) {
 for (int i = 0; i < getLinkCount; i++) {
     elementLink = (Element) Link.item(i);

   // Here you can get these three links.
}
}
```